# Maintain calculated value in Excel

Tags: excel, formulas

I'm trying to use Excel to set up a scoring system for an Alternate Reality Game. I have a sheet that takes all the tasks players complete, scores them, and calculates their total points. From that, it determines their level in the game. They get a point multiplier based on their level, which the formula that calculates the scores references. You can see the problem: every time the multiplier increases, Excel automatically recalculates the points for every task, including the ones that are over and done with, thereby artificially inflating players' scores. Is there some way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Your sheet that logs all of the tasks needs to include the level they achieved the task at. The the total would be a `SUMPRODUCT` of *<task award> × <multiplier for level task was achieved>*.

Comment: I'm just going to put it out there that some code would do this easily.  Other than what Jeeped already suggested, I could think of some layouts, but it would help to see what you are currently doing, and knowing how much you want to modify.  I would think LOG sheet with events logged in it. Then having 'SUMIF' in some formulas calculating the results of those events on other sheets.  A character sheet that fills per character based on dropdown.   The log sheet would probably be best manipulated by a UserForm or something though, but not it's not necessary.

Comment: To summarize that last comment:  I'd make it into a normalized database and have some sheets serve as Reports, that are filled by Queries.  Example: Character Report Sheet, filled after a dropdown list is chosen for which character.

Comment: Thanks, both of you. I like the idea of a UserForm. I haven't tried to do something remotely like this for years, so I'm kind of swimming in deep water for me. @peege, what would be a good way to show you what I have? I don't mind redoing things. I need to have this ready in a couple weeks, though. I'm a teacher and this is for a class activity, so the form is also calculating grades based on the data. I'd like to have a report for each student, ideally. Thanks again.